# Convert to/from date format

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to convert to and from a `DateTime` using `z Y` format (day number/year) but it seems to be off by 1 day:

```
<?php
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('z Y', '239 2016'));
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '28/08/2016'));
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '28/08/2016')->format('z Y'));
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-08-28 01:08:44.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-08-28 01:08:44.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
string(8) "240 2016"
```

https://3v4l.org/p1rnL

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

---

Using day 0/the 1st of Jan seems to work as expected: https://3v4l.org/BqIkM

Comment: What's the problem? You should notice that z is starting from 0. i.e 1-Jan is 0.

Comment: @sємsєм converting from day 239 gives the 28th, but converting back from the 28th gives day 240.

Comment: It is not a bug. `z` counts starting from `0` but the real date format counts from `1` i.e you could not able to find `0 jan 2016` but you can find `1 jan 2016` while in z you know that `0` is `a jan 2016`

Comment: @sємsєм what do you mean "real date format"? They are the same format. Also I noticed that 1st Jan converts to/from 0 just fine: https://3v4l.org/BqIkM

Comment: Try it with the year `2015` or a date before 29 Feb. 2016 and you will understand what I mean. In other words the last day in 2016 (Leap year) is # 365 while in 2015 is 364.

Answer (score -3):

Try setting your default timezone `date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');`